# consuming Dominos webservice from ASp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, lotus-domino

I am trying to consuming a dominos web services from Asp.net. When i add the reference to the dominos webservice it creates a  web reference which has a .wsdl file but no .disco file. Do i need to have the disco file to connect to the webservice.

Please advise.

-thks

Answer (score 2):

I got it. You dont need to have the disco file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.. Here are is a links that is good background reading about webservices in Domino, that may help you be a better "consumer"...LOL

[IBM Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246862.html)